# property 'then' of undefined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I've been trying everything on internet but still got this
error **ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**

try to run it with `ionic cordova run browser` still doesn't work even when I try it on android studio emulator please help me solve this, and this is my code from db.service.ts

````
    private platform: Platform, 
    private sqlite: SQLite, 
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private sqlPorter: SQLitePorter,
  ) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'positronx_db.db',
        location: 'default'
      })
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
          this.storage = db;
          this.getFakeData();
      });
    });
  }

  dbState() {
    return this.isDbReady.asObservable();
  }
 
  fetchSongs(): Observable<Song[]> {
    return this.songsList.asObservable();
  }```
````

Comment: There is multiple `then` in your code, which one is causing the error ? Can you run `ionic info` at the root of your project and post the result ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of plugin doesn't support browser platform. you must try this in real device and i believe everything will work for you.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite

Comment: Did you face this issue in real device too ?

Comment: i try it in real device, still doesn't work

Comment: it should work, can you please uninstall the plugin and app from your device and try to build again and run it in your device.

Comment: done, still doesn't work. or it because my ionic6 because I'm following documentation from ionic 4 and 5